# Get the latest value from repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table named `Report_Table` in Azure SQL. It has more than one hundred columns.

I will give an example with 3 columns like:

```
+--------+----------+------+
| job_id | rep_pm   | done |
+--------+----------+------+
|  46    | a002     |    a |
|  47    | a002     |    b |
|  48    | a002     |    c |
|  49    | a003     |    d |
|  50    | a003     |    e |
|  51    | a003     |    f |
|  52    | a004     |    g |
|  53    | a004     |    h |
|  54    | a005     |    i |
|  55    | a006     |    j |
+--------+----------+------+
```

Column `rep_pm` have repeating values. I need to fetch the latest value of `rep_pm`.

It will depend upon column `job_id`.

- For `a002` latest `jod_id` will be `48`
- For `a003` latest `jod_id` will be `51`
- For `a004` latest `jod_id` will be `53`

and so on.

I need the latest `job_id`'s for all the `rep_pm`'s and also the remaining columns present in the table.

This is what I tried:

```
select 
    rep_pm, count(*) as cnt,
    row_number() over (partition by rep_pm order by count(*) desc) as seq
from 
    Report_Table 
group by 
    rep_pm
```

Above query is returning this output:

```
+--------+----------+------+
| rep_pm | cnt      | seq  |
+--------+----------+------+
|  a002  | 3        |    1 |
|  a003  | 3        |    1 |
|  a004  | 2        |    1 |
|  a005  | 1        |    1 |
|  a005  | 1        |    1 |
+--------+----------+------+
```

I know I am missing something important, would appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try :-

```
 select rt.*  
 from Report_Table rt
 join (select rep_pm,max(job_id) as job_id from Report_Table group by rep_pm)x
 on rt.job_id=x.job_id and rt.rep_pm=x.rep_pm
```

Comment: Thanks @Somendra.. Your Solution is working good too..

Answer (score 1):

> Get the latest value from repeating values

Yes, if you would like to get the latest `job_id` for all `rep_pms` and also the remaining columns present in your table, you can try to use this SQL query:

```
SELECT rep_pm, job_id, done
FROM 
(
  SELECT rep_pm, job_id, done,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rep_pm ORDER BY job_id DESC) 
    AS seq

  FROM Report_Table
) 
AS t
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Zufar.. Please give me some time. I will test and get back to you

Comment: @Goku yes, sure. Take your time

Comment: It is working good +1 ...Unfortunately I can mark only one answer

Comment: I really don't think we need *another* [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) answer...